# What is the difference between bendpoints in JBPM 3 plugin for Eclipse and JPBM 4 plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm, eclipse-gef

In JBPM 3 plugin for Eclipse, bendpoints are represented using four integers:

```
<transition name="">
  <label x="5" y="-10"/>
  <bendpoint w1="36" h1="-37" w2="43" h2="39"/>
</transition>
```

In the source code, there is a class called `Bendpoint`, which stores two `Dimension` objects whose values are represented by w1, h1, w2 and h2. This seems to come from Eclipse GEF.

In JBPM 4 plugin for Eclipse, bendpoints are represented by two integers:

```
<transition name="" g="200,100:5,-10" />
```

In the source code, there is not such a Bendpoint class. The values are now stored in a simpler `Point` class.

**How can I convert JBPM 3 bendpoints to JBPM 4 format?**

*Note*: the above code is just an example. I don't know what JBPM 3 values will be like in JBPM 4.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the bendpoint is related to the bendpoints of a bendpoint. If you check in the plugin, the bendpoint is only filled in the file, when you make a bend in the transition. Otherwise, no bendpoint is added to it.

So, after you have made a bend, a bendpoint is filled like the following:

```
<bendpoint w1="36" h1="-37" w2="43" h2="39"/>
```

This bendpoint informs you of 2 coordinates (w1,h1) and (w2,h2). The first is related to the origin node of the transation, and the second is related to the destin node of the transation.

I hope this helps you. Good luck!